# adding type="date" to the text_field elements

Tags: page-object-gem

I have an input element that has the type="date" as an attribute and when I attempt to define a page-object element as text_field then it is not found.

This is the html

```
<input id="dteVStartPicker" type="date"style="">
```

I'm asking as i have a widget created and would like to use the

```
class SendkeyField < PageObject::Elements::TextField
,,,
PageObject.register_widget :sendkey_field, SendkeyField, :text_field
```

This is what i would like my page_object to be

```
 sendkey_field(:start_date, :id="dteVStartPicker")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an outstanding feature request for this - https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/307.

For now, I would suggest monkey-patching the functionality into the Accessors module. This is basically what the feature request will need to add.

```
require 'page-object'

module PageObject
  module Accessors
    def date_field(name, identifier={:index => 0}, &block)
      define_method("#{name}_element") do
        return call_block(&block) if block_given?
        platform.date_field(identifier.clone)
      end

      define_method("#{name}?") do
        self.send("#{name}_element").exists?
      end    

      define_method(name) do
        self.send("#{name}_element").value
      end

      define_method("#{name}=") do |value|
        self.send("#{name}_element").value = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then your page object would be:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  date_field(:start_date, id: 'dteVStartPicker')
end
```

Which gives a setter and getter for the field:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
page.start_date = '2019-11-02'
p page.start_date
#=> '2019-11-02'
```

Comment: Thank you.  Good reminder for me to look feature request as well when looking for answers.